# Put icons in line mikepenz material drawer

Tags: android, material-design

I use mikepenz material drawer. Its good, but I cant found some methods. I want to put menu`s inons in the same line , not in column and create them "clickable". Like in this picture:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QucDM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that this is at the moment not possible.

For feature requests please visit the library project site on Github and create an issue: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/